# SQL deadlock in RDS from AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sqs

I have an SQL Server RDS instance and I am uploading a huge payroll excel file (approx 500 records/rows to 75000 records/rows) over S3 that eventually inserts payroll records into AWS SQS (one record per message).

I have a processing .netcore Lambda that is triggered by SQS to insert or update payroll data. The processing lambda failing because of transaction deadlock. Almost records are failing with the message:

*Transaction (Process ID 90) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.*

I am not using any transaction in my SQL statements. Is there any way to handle connection pooling or some way to sort out this issue.

I tried some ways, like creating a single SQL connection object and use it thru processing lambda but no progress. I referred some articles that suggests to declare SQL connection object outside processing lambda handler, because in most cases when there is recurrent execution happens, chances are there that same lambda container is reused (but can't be sure of). In that case, I can have same Sql connection object be reused (Reference: https://www.jeremydaly.com/reuse-database-connections-aws-lambda/). But, It did not help in my case. I tried keeping SQS batch size 1 to 10 when triggering processing lambda, but same result.

Comment: Review your Lambda logs.  You should find that the SQS/Lambda integration is keeping approximately 5 Lambda invocations running at the same time, in 5 different containers, with 5 db connections, and 1 different message each.  This is unrelated to batch size, connection pools, or the way the actual Lambda code is written. Check this?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, should that create problem for an RDS with m4.large Sql Server Standard Edition?

Comment: SQL Server is not my specialty but RDBMS deadlocks, in general, are not related to server capacity but rather to concurrent execution of specific queries -- when two (or more) queries end up trying to lock database objects in such a way that each is blocking the other, then those queries are said to 
be *deadlocked*, and at least one must be killed by the system when the condition is detected, otherwise they would literally both wait forever since they are at an impasse.  This is sometimes, but not always, triggered by queries and database design that are sub-optimal.

Comment: Found the issue. There was a trigger written over the table in which lambda function instances were writing records to. The select statement inside trigger was causing deadlock